# Laravel wrong url

Tags: laravel, routes

I have Showroompage Controller

```
    public function index()
{

    if (request()->category) {
        $products = Product::with('categories')->whereHas('categories', function ($query) {
            $query->where('slug', request()->category);
          
        })->take(0)->paginate(9);
        
        $categories = Category::all();
    } else {
        $products = Product::inRandomOrder()->take(0)->paginate(9);
        $categories = Category::all();
    }

    return view('/pages/showroom')->with([
        'products' => $products,
        'categories' => $categories,
    ]);
```

And Route

```
Route::resource('/showroom', App\Http\Controllers\ShowroomPageController::class);

Route::get('showroom/{product}', 'ShoowroomPageController@show' )->name('show');
```

My site display wrong title of url
[image: link]

**What i can do to display in a url "baran-ogrodzenia.pl/showroom/kategoria=bramy-skrzydlowe" instead of "showroom?category"?**

[SITE LINK](https://baran-ogrodzenia.pl)

Comment: you can use the route: `showroom/{product}/{category}`, so your first parameter will be product and second will be a category

Comment: it will be look like this:`baran-ogrodzenia.pl/showroom/bramy-skrzydlowe`

Comment: Your route has a parameter `product`, you try to add `category`.  the route will also be `baran-ogrodzenia.pl/showroom/kategoria/bramy-skrzydlowe` not `baran-ogrodzenia.pl/showroom/kategoria=bramy-skrzydlowe` Please read the documentation on laravel routing.

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question yesterday?

Comment: @GertB. yes he asked this question yesterday

Comment: @Patryk, will you put your get route above your resource route and check, that will be work I think.